# In a PHTML template, how would I determine if the module rendering me is a specific module?

Tags: module, magento-1, template

For example, I have a root template shared by all customer account pages. I want to display a link to the dashboard on all pages except the dashboard (obviously).

How could I detect the page is the dashboard (from PHTML) and hide it? Like this:

```
<?php if (someMagicDetectTheModuleMethod() !== 'someDashboardIdentifier'): ?>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate method using only phtml is to check for the update handle in the current array of handles:

```
<?php if (in_array('customer_account_index', $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles())): ?>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

They layout handles would probably be the easiest way

```
var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

Also you can use the module name as given in the URL

```
var_dump(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName());
```

Comment: Can you pull the "module name" (I have no idea if that's the right wording) specifically? Effectively what you see in XML, I'd be looking for this value: customer_account_index

Comment: Aside: I actually consider doing this type of thing in XML to be an anti-pattern. It splits your code in half and that's confusing. It's clearer to keep this as close to the content as possible (in PHTML).

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if it helped

Comment: getModuleName() would return "customer" for some sub-pages of the dashboard too, so that's not enough to identify it but might be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with a mixture of xml/phtml before. So in the xml you'd set some data against the block only for the dashboard layout handle:

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.block">
        <action method="setData"><name>is_dashboard</name><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

and then in your phtml file you check if that data is set:

```
<?php if ($this->getIsDashboard()): ?>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Always aiming to avoid XML to keep the code in one place (even if XML is more "correct").

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that in a template, you should create a block method which would have something like:

```
public function isDashboardPage()
{
    $page = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    if(strpos($page, 'somedashobaridentifier') !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you should call that method in the template:

```
<?php if($this->isDashboardPage()): ?>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not aiming for the purest method. Splitting this between the frontend and backend code is less maintainable. Same reason I'm trying not to use XML.

Comment: You could also do something similar in a template but it's a lot less pretty.